# Apache times out on the input socket

Tags: python, apache, flask

I am using Flask module of Python and run it through WSGI module of apache2 httpd. The configuration looks like this.

```
httpd.conf:
...
WSGISocketPrefix <somedir>/wsgisock
include sites-enabled
```

And then in my python code, I am invoking Flask in this manner:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request
```

My python program receives a payload and, in response, executes a long task which usually takes more than 30 minutes. At the end it returns a response body. However, at that time I see this message in the error output file:

```
[reqtimeout:info] [pid 7036] [client xxx.xx.xxx.xx:37038] AH01382: Request body read timeout
```

And I ran strace on the httpd process and found this:

```
brk(NULL)                               = 0x7fd2b961a000
brk(0x7fd2b963b000)                     = 0x7fd2b963b000
write(6, "[Sat Oct 21 15:02:21.771995 2017"..., 127) = 127
writev(10, [{"HTTP/1.1 201 CREATED\r\nDate: Sat,"..., 257}, {"{\n  
\"outcomeDetails\": \"Successfu"..., 2873}, {"", 0}], 3) = 3130
write(8, "xxx.xx.xxx.xx - - [21/Oct/2017:1"..., 183) = 183
times({tms_utime=0, tms_stime=0, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 714623894
close(11)                               = 0
shutdown(10, SHUT_WR)                   = 0
poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 1, 2000) = 0 (Timeout)
close(10)                               = 0
read(4, 0x7fff5156c92f, 1)              = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily 
unavailable)
accept4(3,
```

So clearly the httpd process did write to the socket. However I don't see anything coming at the client side (a Java servlet). Anyone knows how to fix this?

Here is my python code:

```
#!usr/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request
import threading, myClass, time, inspect, sys, pprint, os

app = Flask(__name__)

# Dictionary to store threadname, output and returnvalue of task being executed

threads_n_outputs = {'task_string' : {'threadName' : 'thread1', 'logFile' : 'logFile', 'executionResult' : {}}} 

tasks = {
    'myTask1': {
        'Description': u'blah blah', 
    'inputParams': {'var1': u'','var2': u''},
    'outputParams': {'taskOutcome': u'', 'outcomeDetails': u'', 'reversePayload': {}}
    },
    'myTask2': {
        'Description': u'blah blah blah',
    'inputParams': {'var1': u'','var2': u''},
    'outputParams': {'taskOutcome': u'', 'outcomeDetails': u'', 'reversePayload': {}}
    }
}


@app.route('/some/path')
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify(tasks)

# Get method to list specific tasks 

@app.route('/some/path/<task_name>')
def get_task(task_name):
    if tasks[task_name]:
        return jsonify(tasks[task_name])
    else:
    abort(404)

# Get method to show status of a running task

@app.route('/some/path/status/<task_string>')
def showStatus(task_string):
    global threads_n_outputs
    if task_string == 'allRunningJobs':     # Show all running jobs
    temp_dict = dict(threads_n_outputs)
    del temp_dict['task_string']
    if temp_dict:
        return jsonify(temp_dict.keys())
    else:
        return 'No running jobs as of now.'
    if task_string in threads_n_outputs:    # show status for specific job
    with open(threads_n_outputs[task_string]['logFile'], 'r') as fileHandle:
            return jsonify(fileHandle.read().splitlines())
    else:
    return 'No running job named ' + task_string + ' as of now.'

class runTaskClass(threading.Thread):
    global threads_n_outputs
    def __init__(self, functionName, kwargs, task_string, logFile):
        super(runTaskClass, self).__init__(name = task_string)
        self.functionName = functionName 
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    self.task_string = task_string
    self.logFile = logFile 

    def run(self):
    try:
        # Write to logfile instead of stdout
        with open(self.logFile, "w", 1) as fileHandle: 
                with fileHandle as sys.stdout:
                    print '\n' + 'Starting ' + self.task_string + ' at ' + str(time.ctime()) + '\n'
                    threads_n_outputs[self.task_string]['executionResult'] = self.functionName(**self.kwargs)
                    print '\n' + 'Task ' + self.task_string + ' completed at ' + str(time.ctime()) + '\n'
            sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ # Reset stdout to normal
    except Exception, inst:
        fileHandle.close()      # Close file if exception occured within 'with' statement
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ # Reset stdout to normal
            print '\n' + 'runTaskClass : Error While running ' + str(self.task_string) + ' - ' + str(inst)

# Post method to execute a task

@app.route('/some/path/<task_string>', methods=['POST'])    ## task_string comprises of taskname and querytstring to get status of task
def execute_task(task_string):
    print request.get_data()        # print raw input data
    sys.stdout.flush()

    requestData = request.get_json()

    if not requestData: 
    print '\n' + 'ERROR : Posted data is not valid' + '\n'
        abort(400)

    outputParams={'taskOutcome': u'', 'outcomeDetails': u'', 'reversePayload': {}}

    def updateOutputParams(taskOutcome, outcomeDetails, reversePayload):
    outputParams.update(dict(zip(['taskOutcome', 'outcomeDetails', 'reversePayload'],[taskOutcome, outcomeDetails, reversePayload])))
    return jsonify(outputParams), 201

    if len(task_string.split('_')) < 2:             ## If task_string is not in desired format exit with error
        return updateOutputParams('Failure','Error: task_string format should be taskname_queryString', None)

    task_name = task_string.split('_')[0]

    task_details=task_name + ' with arguments ' + ",".join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in requestData.items()])
    print '\n' + 'Executing '+ task_details + '\n'
    task_instance=<someclass>.<someclass>() 
    task_instance.logon()
    functionName='task_instance.' + task_name
    logFile=task_instance.logDirectory + '/td_' + task_string + '.log' # logfile for this job

    if os.path.isfile(logFile):
    newlogFile = logFile + time.strftime("%d%b%Y_%Hh%Mm%Ss")
    os.rename(logFile, newlogFile)

    #Verify if task domain function named task_name exists
    try:
    if callable(eval(functionName)):
        print '\n' + 'Verified that '+ functionName +' is a valid function. Proceeding with validation of arguments.'
    else:
        return updateOutputParams('Failure', 'Error:' + functionName + ' is not a valid function.', None)
    except:
    return updateOutputParams('Failure', 'Exception:' + functionName + ' is not a valid function.', None)

    #Verify if arguments count provided for task_name function is valid

    if len(requestData.items()) + 1 == len(inspect.getargspec(eval(functionName))[0]):  # +1 for first argument 'this'
    print '\n' + 'Argument count for ' + functionName + ' is valid. Proceeding with execution of this function now.' + '\n' 
    else:
    return updateOutputParams('Failure','Error:Argument count for ' + functionName + ' does not match with definition.', None)

    #Initialize the placeholder variable for this thread

    global threads_n_outputs

    #Never start a thread if another thread with same name is running at the moment

    if task_string in threads_n_outputs:
    return updateOutputParams('Failure','Error: Job named ' + task_string + ' is already running. Please submit with distinct identifier', None)
    else:
        threads_n_outputs[task_string] = {'thread': None, 'logFile' : logFile, 'executionResult' : {}}

    #Call task_name function

    try:
    print '\n' + 'Initializing Thread for job ' + str(task_string) + ' ...'
        threads_n_outputs[task_string]['thread'] = runTaskClass(eval(functionName), requestData, task_string, logFile)
        threads_n_outputs[task_string]['thread'].start()
        threads_n_outputs[task_string]['thread'].join()
    print '\n' + 'Thread for job ' + str(task_string) + ' completed.'
        executionResult=threads_n_outputs[task_string]['executionResult']
    print '\n' + 'Execution result for Thread ' + str(task_string) + ' :'
    pprint.pprint(executionResult)

        # handle exception of executionResult['outcomeDetails'] being None when outcome of successful jobs like startVM result None object
        if executionResult['outcomeDetails'] is None:
            executionResult['outcomeDetails'] = 'None'

        outcomeDetails='Successfully executed ' + task_details + ', Outcome details = ' + executionResult['outcomeDetails'] if executionResult['taskOutcome'] == 'Success' else 'Execution failed for ' + task_details + ':Error message is - ' + executionResult['outcomeDetails']

        # Delete current thread's info from threads_n_outputs

        del threads_n_outputs[task_string]

        return updateOutputParams(executionResult['taskOutcome'], outcomeDetails, executionResult['reversePayload'])

    except Exception, inst:
    del threads_n_outputs[task_string]
    print '\n' + 'While running ' + str(task_string) + ' : ERROR ' + str(inst)
        return updateOutputParams('Failure', 'While running ' + str(task_string) + ' : ERROR ' + str(inst), None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5011, debug=True)
```

Comment: This `from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request` doesn't really demonstrate how you're "invoking flask".  Those are just some import statements.  What does your wsgi module look like?

Comment: Relatedly, have you looked at your [`mod_reqtimeout`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html) configuration?  Depending on what OS you're on there might be some defaults in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/reqtimeout.conf` or something like that.

Comment: I have included the python code in the original post.

Comment: @Iguananaut, yes I have looked at that module. I thought the read header timeout and read body timeouts were related to how long will the process keep reading. In my case, it is the write that is failing after a long time of inactivity from the httpd perspective.

Comment: Do you have any problems with your app if you run it outside Apache (e.g. `app.run(...)`)?  That is, is the problem with your app, or with the Apache/mod_wsgi configuration?

Comment: Trying to run it outside apache as you suggested. WIll let you know. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I tried running, but the original intent to use apache was to retain the session. I am not the author of this python code, so I don't know why it doesn't complete all the tasks. So I will have to revert back to apache. I am going to try mod_reqtimeout parameters.

Comment: Yeah, but did it work or not without Apache?  Because that would matter a lot in terms of pointing in the right direction.  The code you showed is probably too stripped down to really indicate the problem.  For example, you wrote that it's doing some long processing on the input data.  If it's reading the input data as a stream while processing, then that would keep the initial request open, and thus lead to Apache timing out the request.  What you might try is changing the settings mod_reqtimeout *just* for the endpoints on which you're making these long requests on.

Comment: It didn't work, but in that case the issue was not related to timeout. I am sorry I couldn't investigate it further as this timeout issue is more urgent. Someone advised me that websockets are more suitable for this kind of applications.

Comment: Unless you can find a way to narrow down the problem more it might not be possible to give an answer.  In particular without seeing your real code (or at least a stripped down non-proprietary facsimile that exhibits the same problem) it may be impossible to say.  As it is this is too broad I think, though I suspect my previous comment may be relevant.  And indeed, web sockets may be more appropriate for a long-running open communication between client and server than holding open an HTTP connection.